# Interact with buttons inside of an aria list-item

Tags: javascript, html, accessibility, wai-aria

In our current frontend we want to add accessibility improvements. The current challenge is to make the list of items including additional actions more accessible. Our document structure is based on the following idea:

```
<div class="products-list" role="list">
  <div class="product" role="listitem">
    <div class="product-name">Product A</div>
    <div class="product-actions>
      <div class="action-icon" role="button">First</div>
      <div class="action-icon" role="button">Second</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

At the moment it's possible to select the list-items, however the a11y border highlights the entire list item (`div.product`). Hence it's not possible to focus the buttons. Defining a sublist using list/listitem roles for `div.product-actions` was not of benefit. Do you have any ideas how to achive this?

Comment: Is the problem not the fact that your `<div role="button"` do not have a `tabindex`, adding `role="button"` only adds semantic info it doesn't add functionality. Use a `<button>` instead and save yourself a load of headaches, otherwise you need to add tabindex, enter and space handlers, focus indicators etc.

Comment: Agreed don't use divs when a button is the proper element and gives you all its benefits. Your button labels need to be clear, though. What does "first" and "second" mean to a screenreader user, for example?

Comment: Can you include a [mcve]?  There's nothing shown here indicating why the entire `div.product` would be focused...

Comment: I'm assuming lots of details were left out of the code snippet, including event handlers and such and that it was mainly to show the structure of the page.  Real `<button>` and `<ul>/<li>` elements are hopefully used in the real code.  But given the lack of details, the `role="listitem"` is not currently selectable because it's not an interactive element so I'm not following why you're seeing a border (focus indicator).